# Access Database Using two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that have a common field Class and Class Offered. I am trying to create a query that will display a list of records from the first table with those records from the second table that have the same class name in a second list. Is this possible. My table fields are:

**Table 1**

```
Class, First_Name, Last_Name.
```

**Table 2**

```
Class Offered, First_Name, Last_Name.
```

I would like the query/report to show:

```
List One                 List Two
Table One                Table Two (where the class name is the same)
```

Comment: have you tried `join`s????

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.* from table1 inner join table2 on table1.class = table2.classoffered
```

OR

```
select * from table1 where exists (select 1 from table2 where table1.class= table2.classoffered)
```

Comment: This only shows the data from one table but thanks anyway. Sara